# Quadratic and Linear Function relationship

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, systems-of-equations, quadratics

I just stumbled across this problem and would appreciate some help with it, as I'm not getting far with it.

**Problem:** You are given a quadratic function $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$
and a linear function $g(x)$.

The two functions intersect at $x=0$ and at also at an $x$ with $g(x)=f(x)=0$ and where $x<0$.

Which of the two could, for some values of $a,b,c$, be an expression for $g(x)$:

1. $g(x)=bx+c$
2. $g(x)=ax+c$

**My Progress thus far:**
We know that the $y$-intercept must be $c$, because $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ intercept at $x=0$. So that makes perfect sense. However I fail to see how for some values of $a,b,c$  the gradient of $g(x)$ could either be $a$ or $b$.
Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given f(x)=$ax^2$+bx+c ($a \neq0$),

if g(x)=bx+c for some x=$x_1$<0,

f($x_1$)=${ax_1}^2$+$bx_1$+c (I)

g($x_1$)=b$x_1$+c  (II)

(I)-(II)  ${ax_1}^2$ = 0, a=0 , it is not allowed.

So, this is not the right choice, only option is (2)  g(x)=ax+c.

You can prove that from here.